# How to reject invalid insert operations in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, triggers, insert

I have a table called `Score`. Score means the "marks" of "Active" students. So there is another table called `Student` and it has a `Activation` column (boolean) to find out whether the student is active or not.

Now, When inserting the score to the `Score` table, I need to check whether the student is active or not, if inactive then do not accept the `insert` else accept the `insert`.

I tried to do this by creating a `Trigger` in `Score` but it seems like it is not the solution, because triggers seems cannot do it. I am using JDBC, so I can pretty easily find out whether the student is active or not by running a query before the `insert` statement, but I think I have to add this rule to the database too, so no one can add the score of an inactive student to the DB even by directly working with the DB, outside the java program.

Or else, just validating this in Java program is enough?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to check first?

Comment: @Strawberry: Imagine someone is going to insert something into the database without using the application. Maybe the user's data entry   guy is going to mess around and apply some data directly using the PHPMyAdmin or something. Then since the program is not there, these values will be taken to the database whether they aree right or wrong. Or may be I am worrying too much abt this?

Comment: But you could do that with a join !?!?!

Comment: Insert into m(x,y,z) SELECT 'a','b','c' FROM j JOIN k ON something = something WHERE another thing = 'active'

Comment: @Strawberry: As I mentioned before, I am not looking for a solution which I have to do in client program.

Comment: Ok, have you looked at constraints?

Comment: @Strawberry: `Check` constraints? Yeah, but it is simply used to check whether the data are in valid range etc etc isnt it..

Comment: @Strawberry: Right now I am thinking about `Signals`. Here is my question abt it, bcs that also didnt work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201429/mysql-unable-to-use-signal-sqlstate-in-trigger

Answer (score 1):

@Sniper, Write a condition on your front end

1.Write a `query` to check whether the student is active 
2.If so do your `insert` stuff
3.Else do nothing.

Comment: I know I can do it in Java program easily. I am interested in applying this to the database too.