# MySQL: Unable to use SIGNAL in Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, signals

I am trying to generate an error message using the MySQL trigger. Below is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Initial_Fees`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT Activation from Portfolio WHERE idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio)=false) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'Disabled Thing';
    END IF;
END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

But this always generates an error. I don't know what the error is, because It is not saying anything about the error, it is just "Error".

Any advice on this please? Apart from that, some people say using `SIGNAL` is subjected to issues because it can be MySQL version dependent. Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `set message_text` clause is part of the signal syntax - there should not be a semicolon (`;`) between them.
Additionally, it uses a `=` operator, not a `:=`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Initial_Fees`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT Activation from Portfolio WHERE idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio)=false) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' -- Note: no semicolon
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Disabled Thing'; -- Note the = operator
    END IF;
END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I added this code in MySQL Work bench and exported the sql file and things went fine! I don't know what has happened with PHP MyAdmin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin gives you the option of specifying the delimiter you use in your SQL.

I specified `$$` as the delimiter instead of `;` BUT Mysql is still expecting `;` in some places. So

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_wp_posts BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_posts
    FOR EACH ROW
        IF (NEW.post_content LIKE '%<script%>%') THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Script not allowed in post';
    END IF;
```

Fails

but

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_wp_posts BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_posts
    FOR EACH ROW
    IF (NEW.post_content LIKE '%<script%>%') THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Script not allowed in post';
    END IF$$
```

Works