# CREATE UNIQUE INDEX using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble using a where clause on CREATE UNIQUE INDEX on mysql. I know you cannot just add where clause at the end of CREATE UNIQUE INDEX. Example below.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FAKE_TABLE_INDEX ON TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAME) WHERE INACTIVE = 0;
```

and this query above gives me an error. So is there alternative I can do to fix this query.

Comment: If you know that MySQL does not support filtered indexes, then why are you trying to create one?

Comment: @GordonLinoff He's asking how to do something equivalent in MySQL.

Comment: @AhmedRasmi . . .  No matter how you approach this, I think you need a trigger.

Comment: I saw somewhere that they used VIEW. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160530/use-len-function-in-where-clause-in-create-unique-indexBut I do not think it is going to work. How would I use a trigger?

Comment: related https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-to-create-a-conditional-index-in-mysql

Comment: @niceman delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER is_trigger_set CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fake_table_index ON table_name (column_name)
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF New.inactive = 0
   END IF;
END;//
delimiter ; That of course does not work but do you have clue how i would use trigger on CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ?

Comment: @niceman You are a life saver!!!!!!! That works!!!!! Use this link everyone 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201429/mysql-unable-to-use-signal-in-trigger

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't have filtered indexes. If I understand what they do (from reading the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes)) I think the closest analogous feature is multi-column indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX fake_table_index ON table_name (inactive, column_name);
```

This is more expensive than the filtered index because it indexes all the values of `inactive`, not just where `inactive = 0`.

This also doesn't have the unique constraint that the filtered index does. It's only useful for optimizing queries, not enforcing uniqueness. You'll have to do that with a trigger if you need it.

Comment: . . This doesn't do the same thing.  Presumably, `inactive` is a flag with two values, and the intention is that only one "active" row be allowed per "id".

Comment: @GordonLinoff True, I was only considering the performance aspects of an index, not the constraints. I've updated the answer to point out this caveat.